# unable to generate the PDF from the XML string using xsl-fo in Fop

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo

I am using Fop to generate the PDF file and i have the xml and xsl source to transform xsl-fo object but the PDF file is displaying as blank please help me on this...

This is my Xml response as string:

```
 <enqResponse>…<cols><c>ID</c><c>DESCRIPTION</c></cols>….<r><c><cap>1111</cap><i>4</i></c><c><cap>Banks</cap></c></r>… </enqResponse>
```

And This is my Xslt file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="enqResponse">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="50in" page-height="80in">
          <fo:region-body  margin-top="1in" margin-bottom="1in" />
          <fo:region-before extent="2in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
          <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
               <fo:block font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></fo:block>
          </fo:static-content>
          <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block><xsl:apply-templates select="cols"/></fo:block>
          <fo:block><xsl:apply-templates select="r"/></fo:block>     
        </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cols">
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <!--<fo:table-column column-width="2in"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="4in"/>
                  --><fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                             <xsl:for-each select="c">
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell> 
                     </xsl:for-each>                
                    </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="r">
         <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <!--<fo:table-column column-width="12in"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="12in"/>
                     --><fo:table-body>
                     <fo:table-row>
                            <xsl:for-each select="c">
                                  <fo:table-cell>
                                  <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="cap"/></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                     </xsl:for-each>  
                </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I download the xml out as PDF it generate the blank pdf file kindly give your suggestion on this and let me know id anything wrong in xslt file.

Where as I have the xslt file with static content and it displayed properly as PDF the Xslt file with static content

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="enqResponse">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
          <fo:region-body margin="2in"/>
          <fo:region-before extent="1.0cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
          <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" >
               <fo:block font-size="12pt" text-align="center">Page-1/1</fo:block>
          </fo:static-content>
          <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block space-after="1.0cm">Welcome</fo:block>
          <fo:block>
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                       <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                      <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>No</fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Name</fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Phone Number</fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>

                    <fo:table-row>
                      <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Test1</fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Test2</fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Test3</fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                       </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please give the solution to extract the dynamic data from the given xml string to generate the  PDF file ...........

Comment: Which version of XSL-FO processor are you using, and what is the error output when you run it?

Comment: @Woody - The processor is FOP. It's mentioned in the title and the first sentence of the question.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake, I didn't see what version of the FOP processor was being used in either of those places - guess I am not as good at reading as you! As the output and processing changes massively between versions 0.2/0.9x and 1.0, it is kind of relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Using either FOP or XEP (RenderX), I get a pdf with the generated text. (Some of the text is off the left margin though.)

Are you sure your PDF is blank? Since you're generating a 50in x 80in page (wow!), maybe you just can't see the text.